# How to use multiple decorators with spyne

Tags: python, web-services, wcf, python-decorators, spyne

I have a problem with multiple decorators with spyne. I want to add universal try/except decorator to each method in class. My code looks like this:

```
def try_except(fn):
       def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
           try:
               return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           except Exception:
               do_sth()
   return wrapped

class A(ServiceBase):

@rpc(Unicode, Integer, _returns=[Boolean, Integer], _out_variable_names=["FooResult", "bar"])
@try_except
def Foo(self, foo, bar):
    do_sth()
    return True, 0
```

With @try_except I get number of arguments error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the traceback?

Comment: Note that decorators are applied *"inside out"*, so any error thrown from the code in the `rpc` wrapper won't be caught by `try_except`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend decorators. Not because they are not supported, but because they are not very powerful and also have cryptic behaviour.

For exception handling, you can override `call_wrapper` function of either `Application` or `ServiceBase` in a class in your project and use it instead of stock Spyne classes. You should have your try/except block surround the `super()` call.

See API docs for [ServiceBase.call_wrapper](http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/reference/service.html#spyne.service.ServiceBase.call_wrapper) and [Application.call_wrapper](http://spyne.io/docs/2.9/reference/application.html#spyne.application.Application.call_wrapper).

You don't like to do this? You can add event handlers to your service classes or applications. The [events example](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/master/examples/user_manager/server_basic.py) can get you started.

You still want to use decorators? See [this FAQ entry](http://spyne.io/docs/2.9/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-use-other-decorators-with-rpc-srpc). Quoting the relevant bits:

> ```
> from decorator import decorator
>
> def _do_something(func, *args, **kw):
>     print "before call"
>     result = func(*args, **kw)
>     print "after call"
>     return result
>
> def my_decor(f):
>     return decorator(_do_something, f)
>
> class SomeService(ServiceBase):
>     @my_decor
>     @srpc(Integer, _returns=Integer)
>     def testf(first):
>         return first
> ```
>
> Note that the place of the decorator matters. Putting it before @srpc will make it run once, on service initialization. Putting it after will make it run every time the method is called, but not on initialization.

Again, don't use decorators!!

You have been warned :)